# single make target for copying files from different locations to one place

Tags: makefile

I need to copy `YUV` sequence **from** **3 different locations from the server** and put at common **input** folder in my file structure using make file.

I wrote a target in make file which works good for copying input from one server location only.

```
VID_INPUT_YUV_PATH = ../input
VID_INPUT_YUV_FILES =   \
    input0.yuv
VID_INPUT_YUV = $(addprefix $(VID_INPUT_YUV_PATH)/, $(VID_INPUT_YUV_FILES))
VID_INPUT_NOCLEAN = $(addprefix -e , $(VID_INPUT_YUV))

.PRECIOUS: $(VID_INPUT_YUV_PATH)/%.
$(VID_INPUT_YUV_PATH)/%:
    mkdir -p $(VID_INPUT_YUV_PATH)
    scp server:/stdDataset/airbus/$(notdir $@) $@
```

**Expectation:**

1. Copy **input0** from **server:/stdDataset/airbus** to `input` folder
2. Copy **input1** from **server:/stdDataset/train** to `input` folder
3. Copy **input2** from **server:/stdDataset/car** to `input` folder

**Query:**
Is there any optimized way instead of writing separate target (3 make target) for copying all 3 at one location.

Comment: Best I can think of is target specific variables. Input-to-server mapping would be like `input0.yuv: INPUT_SERVER_LOCATION:=server:/stdDataset/airbus`, rule like `scp $(INPUT_SERVER_LOCATION)/$(@F) $@`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no algorithmic way to convert the file names into the directory names, you'll have to tell make about that mapping at least.

One way to do it is via [variable names](http://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-macro-names/).  You can do something like this:

```
input0_DIR = airbus
input1_DIR = train
input2_DIR = car

$(VID_INPUT_YUV_PATH)/%:
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        scp server:/stdDataset/$($(@F)_DIR)/$(@F) $@
```

I don't know what that `.PRECIOUS` line is for; doesn't seem useful to me.

Comment: I have two different types of input. input0 and input1 is *.y type .and input2 is .yuv . Weather same make target target will work with this.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "two different types of input"; you're copying files from a remote system.  How can that be "different types of input"?  But, any answer you get is only as good as the information in the question you ask.  The answer here will work, for the question you provided.